# How do I understand why my Heroku app does not work?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a perfectly working `node.js` application that works fine in my cloud IDE. However, when I deploy it (and it succesfully gets deployed) and try to run the application on heroku, then I keep getting the error `503`.

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

In the logs, I also do not see anything that could help me except of
the error 503.

```
2015-10-20T08:54:16.271208+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=MYHOSTURL request_id=63dff973-9a2e-41fe-af32-578dbd360387 fwd="213.205.194.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

What is going on? The app worked fine the first time I deployed it. It is since the second deployment.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more specific information than this and help us to help you. What is your setup? Have you deployed to heroku before? Can you get a vanilla node app to accept a request?

Comment: I have deployed to heroku before and it worked fine. Then I extended it with a couple of similar libraries (e.g. Firebase) and deployed again using git push heroku master. But now I see what I did wrong... I changed the name from server.js to main.js. Having changed it back to server.js now works again.

Comment: If you change the file name of your nodejs file that starts your app, then you need to edit the Procfile text file and change the filename that the node command calls

Answer (score 1):

Since your most recent deploy, your code is crashing your web server. To get more information, turn on debugging in your process, and then use the following command to restart your process, and view the error logs so you can get some more useful information:

```
$ heroku ps:restart; heroku logs --tail
```

Look through those streaming logs, and you should see some language-specific errors describing why things are crashing =)